# Consecutive bit strings?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I can't figure out a solution for these kinds of questions could someone solve an example for me

How many bit strings of length 15 contain 9 consecutive 1’s or 9 consecutive 0’s?

Comment: Exactly $9$, or at least $9$?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to count the total number of bit strings of length 15, but it's harder to count what you're looking for. Instead, let's let $\alpha$ represent a 9-long string of $0$s.  Then what we're looking for are how many unique ways there are to write a 7-long bit string such that $\alpha$ with $\alpha$ in place of one of the bits. That's quite a bit easier to handle.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott it would be helpful if you could show both cause I am trying to practice such questions and sometimes they ask for one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s first count the $15$-bit strings that have exactly $9$ consecutive ones.

If the bit string is $b=b_1b_2\dots b_{15}$, the block of ones can start at $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5,b_6$, or $b_7$. If it starts at $b_1$, $b_{10}$ must be $0$, and bits $b_{11}$ through $b_{15}$ can be anything. That’s five bits that can be set arbitrarily to $0$ or $1$; there are $2^5=32$ ways to do that, so there are $2^5$ $15$-bet strings that begin with a string of exactly $9$ consecutive ones. Similarly, there are $2^5$ that end with such a string. If the string of $9$ ones starts at $b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5$, or $b_6$, on the other hand, it must have a $0$ on **each** end. That accounts for $9+2=11$ bits, leaving only $15-11=4$ bits to be set arbitrarily. In each case this can be done in $2^4=16$ ways. Thus, we get a grand total of $2\cdot2^5+5\cdot2^4=64+80=144$ such bit strings.

There are of course exactly as many that have exactly $9$ consecutive zeroes, and no $15$-bit string can have both, so there are $2\cdot144=288$ $15$-bit strings that contain exactly $9$ consecutive ones or consecutive zeroes.

---

A string of **at least** $9$ ones can still begin at any of the first seven positions. If it begins with $b_1$, we must have $b_1=b_2=\ldots= b_9=1$, but the remaining $6$ bits can be set arbitrarily, since we no longer have to require that $b_{10}=0$; this case therefore yields $2^6$ strings. If it begins with one of $b_2$ through $b_7$, it must be preceded by a zero, so a total of ten bits are determined: a zero followed by $9$ ones. The remaining $5$ bits, however, can be set arbitrarily, so these six cases yield another $6\cdot2^5$ strings. And as before we’ll get just as many with a string of at least $9$ zeroes, so the grand total is $2\left(2^6+6\cdot2^5\right)=512$.

Answer (score 1):

So we're looking at strings like $b_1\ldots b_{15}$ where $b_i = 1$ or $0$. How many ways are there to have nine consecutive ones in a string? We can have $b_i \ldots b_{i + 8}$ consecutive ones, and there $7$ such $i$ that work. So, once we've chosen where to have the nine consecutive ones, how many strings can we build around those? Well, there are $15 - 9 = 6$ free bits left and each choice corresponds to a unique string with $9$ consecutive ones starting in place $i$. So, for each $i$, there are $2^6$ such strings. Thus there are $7 \cdot 2^6$ strings with nine consecutive ones, hence twice that many ones with nine consecutive ones or zeroes (thankfully a length fifteen boolean string cannot have both nine consecutive ones and nine consecutive zeroes). This part answers the "at least nine" portion of the question, as it's possible that we could have chosen some of the next bits to be of the same sign.

For the "exactly nine" portion of the question we have to divide into cases. So I can be more specific, say we're looking for strings with exactly nine consecutive ones. Then we have to divide into three cases: $i = 1$, $i = 7$, and "other". We'll leave the former two cases for last.

In the last ("other") case, because we by definition have at least oen bit of space on either side of the consecutive ones, there are spaces on the left and right of the nine ones. But because we need exactly nine consecutive ones, $b_{i - 1}$ and $b_{i + 9}$ both $have$ to be zero; else we would have too many ones in order. So, really, eleven bits are claimed and we only have four to work with. Thus in this case we're left with $2^4$ possible strings.

In the first case we have that the first 9 bits are ones. By the same argument above the 10th bit must be a zero, so really 10 bits are claimed. We have five more to work with so $2^5$ strings come from this case. The second case is really exactly the same, but inserting the padding zero on the other side.

Thus, we have $2^5$ strings from the last case and $2^6$ from each of the other cases, making for a total of $2^7 + 2^5$ strings with exactly nine consecutive ones. Thus the total number of strings with nine consecutive ones or zeroes is twice that, or $2^8 + 2^6$.